# count specific key: value occurence in a document on sub document level in mongodb using aggregation

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

count specific key: value occurrence in a document on sub document level in mongodb using aggregation

example

```
    {
    "comments" : [ 
    {
        "body" : "est laborum",
        "email" : "ZoROirXN@thUNmWmY.com",
        "author" : "Gisela Levin"
    }, 
    {
        "body" : "aborum",
        "email" : "eAYtQPfz@kVZCJnev.com",
        "author" : "Kayce Kenyon"
    }
     ]
    },
    {
    "comments" : [ 
    {
        "body" : " est laborum",
        "email" : "ZoROirXN@thUNmWmY.com",
        "author" : "Gisela Levin"
    }, 
    {
        "body" : "im id est laborum",
        "email" : "eAYtQPfz@kVZCJnev.com",
        "author" : "Kayce Kenyon"
      }
      ]

     }
```

I just want to know about the query to caluclate how many times a particular author comments

Comment: This is a document of MongoDB university. You should do your homework by investigating the docs and the courseware, not by asking how to solve it on SO. **Disclaimer**: Not affiliated with 10gen or MongoDB university.

Answer (score 1):

```
var author = "someone";

db.c.aggregate({
    $match : {
        "comments.author" : author
    }
}, {
    $unwind : "$comments"
}, {
    $match : {
        "comments.author" : author
    }
}, {
    $group : {
        _id : "$comments.author",
        count : {
            $sum : 1
        }
    }
});
```

**count** is the answer.

Comment: I thought [**`$sum`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/sum/) was the answer, or at least part of it. Part of the problem here being people searching for a "count" operator that does not exist.

Comment: @Neil Lunn, `count` is the key to {$sum:1} after `$group` operation.

Comment: I can read. But I don't think you are clearly stating either "why" you process this way or the "correct" operator that does the work.